# android service started at boot getting force stopped

Tags: android, android-service

I am new to Android.. I was trying to write android service which will be started when device starts. When I run the application with simulator, I am able to see the my debug statements (system.outs) in "adb logcat"; which means my service is getting invoked when bootup is completed. But as per log, entire code in 'onStart' service method is not getting executed. Log is not showing all expected system.outs.

Below is the log showing 'force stopping service' statements (marked in BOLD):-

```
**D/Exchange(  222): BootReceiver onReceive
D/EAS SyncManager(  222): !!! EAS SyncManager, onCreate
I/ActivityManager(   58): Start proc com.webapps.service for broadcast com.webap
ps.service/.MyStartupIntentReceiver: pid=232 uid=10038 gids={1015}
D/EAS SyncManager(  222): !!! EAS SyncManager, onStartCommand
D/EAS SyncManager(  222): !!! EAS SyncManager, stopping self
D/Eas Debug(  222): Logging:
D/EAS SyncManager(  222): !!! EAS SyncManager, onDestroy
**I/System.out(  232): **************MyStartupIntentReceiver******************
I/System.out(  232): **************Service created******************
I/ActivityManager(   58): Start proc com.android.music for broadcast com.android
.music/.MediaAppWidgetProvider: pid=241 uid=10022 gids={3003, 1015}
**I/System.out(  232): **************Service started****************
I/System.out(  232): *********Current date is :=>  2011/Nov/24 11:02:34**
I/ActivityManager(   58): Start proc com.android.quicksearchbox for broadcast co
m.android.quicksearchbox/.SearchWidgetProvider: pid=247 uid=10012 gids={3003}
I/ActivityThread(  247): Publishing provider com.android.quicksearchbox.google:
com.android.quicksearchbox.google.GoogleSuggestionProvider
I/ActivityManager(   58): Start proc com.android.protips for broadcast com.andro
id.protips/.ProtipWidget: pid=255 uid=10007 gids={}
D/PackageParser(   58): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl34597.tmp
W/PackageParser(   58): Unknown element under <application>: uses-permission at
/data/app/vmdl34597.tmp Binary XML file line #18
I/PackageParser(   58): com.webapps.service: compat added android.permission.WRI
TE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
D/MediaScanner(  195):  prescan time: 2646ms
D/MediaScanner(  195):     scan time: 91ms
D/MediaScanner(  195): postscan time: 1ms
D/MediaScanner(  195):    total time: 2738ms
I/PackageManager(   58): Removing non-system package:com.webapps.service
D/dalvikvm(  128): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 4610 objects / 268504 bytes in 125ms
D/PackageManager(   58): Scanning package com.webapps.service
I/PackageManager(   58): Package com.webapps.service codePath changed from /data
/app/com.webapps.service-2.apk to /data/app/com.webapps.service-1.apk; Retaining
 data and using new
I/PackageManager(   58): /data/app/com.webapps.service-1.apk changed; unpacking
D/installd(   34): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.webapps.service-1.apk' ---
I/Launcher.Model(  128): not binding apps: no Launcher activity
D/dalvikvm(  128): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1595 objects / 79016 bytes in 251ms
D/dalvikvm(  261): DexOpt: load 200ms, verify 217ms, opt 2ms
D/installd(   34): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.webapps.service-1.apk' (succes
s) ---
W/PackageManager(   58): Code path for pkg : com.webapps.service changing from /
data/app/com.webapps.service-2.apk to /data/app/com.webapps.service-1.apk
W/PackageManager(   58): Resource path for pkg : com.webapps.service changing fr
om /data/app/com.webapps.service-2.apk to /data/app/com.webapps.service-1.apk
D/PackageManager(   58):   Services: com.webapps.service.SimpleService
D/PackageManager(   58):   Receivers: com.webapps.service.MyStartupIntentReceive
r
I/installd(   34): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.webapps.service-1.apk@cl
asses.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.webapps.service-1.apk@classes.dex
D/PackageManager(   58): New package installed in /data/app/com.webapps.service-
1.apk
D/MediaScannerService(  195): done scanning volume internal
I/ActivityManager(   58): Force stopping package com.webapps.service uid=10038
W/ActivityManager(   58): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.webapps.serv
ice/.SimpleService in 13004ms
I/Process (   58): Sending signal. PID: 232 SIG: 9
**I/ActivityManager(   58):   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{4502c7e0 com.we
bapps.service/.SimpleService}**
W/ActivityManager(   58): setProcessForeground called on unknown pid: 232
E/JavaBinder(   58): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
I/ActivityManager(   58): Force stopping package com.webapps.service uid=10038
**I/ActivityManager(   58): Force stopping package com.webapps.service uid=10038**
D/dalvikvm(  128): GC_EXPLICIT freed 6910 objects / 354424 bytes in 210ms
```

---

Below is my code

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.webapps.service"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <!--<activity android:name=".ServiceController"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> -->

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

        <receiver android:name=".MyStartupIntentReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

       <service android:name=".SimpleService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.wissen.startatboot.SimpleService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

---

```
package com.webapps.service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class SimpleService extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
          return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
          super.onCreate();
          System.out.println("**************Service created****************");
          Toast.makeText(this,"Service created ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
          super.onDestroy();
          System.out.println("**************Service destroyed****************");
          Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        System.out.println("**************Service started****************");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        int cnt=0;
        while (true)
        {
        Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MMM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        String dateNow = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime());
        System.out.println("*********Current date is :=>  " + dateNow);
        cnt++;
        try{
        Thread.sleep (20000);
        }catch (Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
        if (cnt == 4)
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("********CNT*************  " + cnt);
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.webapps.service;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyStartupIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
    serviceIntent.setAction("com.wissen.startatboot.SimpleService");
    System.out.println("**************MyStartupIntentReceiver****************");    
    context.startService(serviceIntent);
}
}
```

---

`SimpleService.java` is defined under package `com.webapps.service`; whereas `MyStartupIntentReceiver` sets `intentAction` as `com.wissen.startatboot.SimpleService`.

Is this causing my service to force stop?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do you work in `onStart`!. `Android` will wait till it returns, which it never does due the while. A timeout will fire and Android will kill your service!

Do you things in an other thread, e.g. `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0):

Does your service crash if you remove the `while(true)` loop? I would guess `onStart` is not expected to execute for too long. 
Also, `Service` is not executed in a separate thread.